# Build error moving from Boost.JSON 1.76 to 1.79 with amiguous overloaded functions, possible work around?

Tags: c++, json, boost, c++17, boost-json

Upgrading from boost 1.76 to 1.79 caused a regression in some code I have been working on. This regression comes in the following build error:

```
In file included from .../boost/json/value.hpp:20,
                 from <list of includes>
                 from .../a.cpp
.../boost/json/string.hpp: In member function ‘int boost::json::string::compare(boost::json::string_view) const’:
.../boost/json/string.hpp:1948: error: call of overloaded ‘basic_string_view(const boost::json::string&amp;)’ is ambiguous
         return string_view(*this).compare(sv);
 
In file included from .../boost/json/string_view.hpp:14,
                 from  <lsit of includes>
                 from .../a.cpp           
.../boost/core/detail/string_view.hpp:391: note: candidate: ‘boost::core::basic_string_view&lt;Ch&gt;::basic_string_view(const std::basic_string_view&lt;Ch, std::char_traits&lt;_CharT&gt; &gt;&amp;) [with Ch = char]’
     basic_string_view( std::basic_string_view&lt;Ch, std::char_traits&lt;Ch&gt; &gt; const&amp; str ) BOOST_NOEXCEPT: p_( str.data() ), n_( str.size() )
 
.../boost/core/detail/string_view.hpp:335: note: candidate: ‘constexpr boost::core::basic_string_view&lt;char&gt;::basic_string_view(const boost::core::basic_string_view&lt;char&gt;&amp;)’
 template&lt;class Ch&gt; class basic_string_view
 
.../boost/core/detail/string_view.hpp:335: note: candidate: ‘constexpr boost::core::basic_string_view&lt;char&gt;::basic_string_view(boost::core::basic_string_view&lt;char&gt;&amp;&amp;)’
```

Here is some example code that I reproduced this with: (GCC 8.2.1, std=c++17)

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
return 0;
}
```

Note it builds with std=c++11 or c++14, however c++17 is a requirment of this project. This error only occurs on linux with GCC. This code builds on Windows with MSVC.

Are there any possible workarounds?

I have tried a couple different tricks using "using" and different namespaces but with the templating it's hard for me to to figure out what is happeneing enough to fix it. I hope I can get this working without changing JSON libraries, or with some other workaround.

Note this build error does not exist with boost 1.76.

Comment: Your program compiles w/o error for me (apple clang 14, libc++, c++17, boost trunk)

Comment: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_80_0.html - `JSON: ... Fixed ambigious conversion to std::string_view on GCC 8.` Why not just use version 1.80?